# What are the main differences between AmE and BrE phrasal verbs?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

What are the main differences between AmE and BrE phrasal verbs?

It seems to me that BrE uses more phrasal verbs than AmE and that the particle of the phrasal verb changes sometimes from AmE to BrE like in the phrasal verb *beat on* (AmE) to *beat on* (BrE).

Am I right? Is there any rule to make this preposition change?

Comment: You've given the ***same*** preposition for both in your question, but you ask about the preposition ***change***. Please clarify.

Comment: I know you're "buzzin' but think more carefully how to phrase the question before posting. :)

Comment: More examples please.

Comment: I think they are mainly the same, but there are a few scattered differences. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English#Phrasal_verbs) only comes up with four. Besides the *beat on* example, it says Americans fill forms *out*, while Brits fill them *in*, and in the US events are rained *out*, while in the UK they're rained *off*.

Comment: I meant beat on and beat up, sorry

Comment: I'm confused. I thought (BrE?) *to beat up* was a phrasal verb, as evidenced by the fact that if, say, *they beat up John* is converted to use a pronoun, it has to be *they beat **him** up*. Would any Americans really say *they beat him on*? If not, is it actually a "phrasal verb" at all?

Comment: @Fumble: No, we'd say they "beat him up" or they "beat on him". The latter basically means they pummeled him. The former could mean the same thing, but it's more broad – the may have kicked him while he was on the ground, for example.

Comment: yes, I admit beat on/up was a bad example. But take the wikipedia examples: fill in (BrE) / fill out (AmE), rain off (BrE)/rain out (AmE). Are there any other examples I should be aware of?

Comment: This is closed as too broad, yet another recent generic question was left up. Hmm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an analysis of this topic here:

> Lui, Dilin. "*The Most Frequently Used English Phrasal Verbs in
>   American and British English: A Multicorpus Examination.*" TESOL
>   Quarterly 45.4 (2011): 661-688.

You will need to be a subscriber to TESOL Quarterly or pay for this particular article. However, there is a review of the article on the [TESOL blog](http://blog.tesol.org/figuring-out-the-frequency-of-two-word-verbs/). Here is an extract from the review:

> But, as a teacher who lives in the United States, but has also spent
>   time in the United Kingdom, I was fascinated by the differences found
>   in the frequency of some verbs that are common in American English,
>   but not in British English and vice versa. For instance, Americans use
>   the following terms much more frequently than the British: *grow up,
>   figure out, show up, check out, pull out, and reach out*.
>
> On the other hand, these expressions were more commonly used in
>   British English: *carry on, fill in, hand over, sort out*, and *pass on*.
>   One of the big differences, of course, is that while Americans *fill
>   out a form*, the British *fill in a form*.

In answer to your last question, phrasal verbs are idioms, and as such are not rule-governed.